Missing part of curve
I have what I think is a simple plot of the normal distribution but for some reason the top of the plot is missing. I hope it's not because I got rid of the y-axis and ticks because I really don't want them in the graph. Here's the code:
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    smooth,
    no marks,
    samples = 20,
    domain=-3:3,
    y axis line style={draw=none},
    ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot+ [name path=normal]{0.3989*exp(-0.5*x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And here is the output:


I was going to delete this but then I thought maybe someone else as lost as me might benefit from the answer I stumbled on: enlargelimits=upper. That simple. I've no idea why it's needed---I assumed the engine figured out what sized frame it needed to graph the function, but it seems not. Anyway, hope this helps some other lost soul!

Interesting. // Can you please show at least the relevant part of your code, where enlargelimits are inserted? Will make life easier for furure readers. Thank you

Good point. I think it can go anywhere in the the list of options for the axis  definition. I put it after after the last element, ytick=\empty before the  ].    //  Another interesting thing: the axis option option "y axis line style-{draw=none}" can be replaced by the simpler, and to me more intuitive, "hide y axis". (From the same source.)   //  Maybe one of the experts who monitor this forum  could explain why the enlargements option is needed, or should we just include in as  a matter of good practice?

BTW, I should note that when I found it I assumed it was extending the Y-AXIS.  But it seems it is extending the X-AXIS, which makes what's going on completely opaque to me. But it solved my problem so I thought I'd share.
